# Pull em database do heroku para local

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

Eu preciso sincronizar os dados do meu banco em produção com o que está no meu local, existe alguma forma de fazer um pull no banco do heroku para o meu em localhost sem ter que criar um novo banco localmente?
A minha aplicação usa o editor Mercury, ou seja o cliente pode alterar algumas alterações diretamente em produção oque significa que quase toda vez eu preciso sincronizar os bancos, eu não queria ter que criar um novo toda vez que precisar atualizar o meu local.
O banco usado é o postgre

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fiz um download do prórprio dashboard do heroku, clicando em Databases você pode baixar um snapshot do banco, o problemaé que ele vem em formato .dump.
Para transformar isso em um formato postgre use o seguinte comando:

> pg_restore --verbose --clean --no-acl --no-owner -h localhost -U userdobanco -d nomedobanco nomedoarquivo.dump

Answer (score 0):

Você pode fazer um migrate no banco de dados com o [Active Record](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/migrations.html) para replicar as suas configurações e depois fazer um [dump](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/backup-dump.html) dos dados para subir os registros.